# Is that a mistake in Lavender movie?

Tags: production-mistakes, lavender

Just finished watching the movie *Lavender*, the story talks about a crime happened in 10 Oct 1985 but in the end of the movie the tombstone shows June 8 1986.

[image]

Is that a mistake or something I missed in the movie?

Comment: To be honest, at this quality I'm totally able to see a `5` in that blurred image equally well to a `6`. Do you have anything more clear to base your question's premise on?